# c# Get algorithm name / oid from certificate template

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, certificate

Using C#, .NET.

Is it possible to get the Algorithm name in the following 2 scenarios please:

A. Provider Category is "Legacy Cryptographic Service Provider" and the Algorithm name is "Determined by CSP"?

[image]

B. Provider Category is "Key Storage Provider" and Algorithm has been specified e.g. "ECDH_P256"

[image]

I am able to query a limited amount of information using the following approach but nothing to figure out the algorithm name, or crypto algorithm oid

```
DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=customerAxForbeTemplate,CN=Certificate Templates,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration");

// Example properties I can access:
dEntry.Properties["name"].Value.ToString();
dEntry.Properties["msPKI-RA-Application-Policies"].Value.ToString();
// ...
```

The latter property "msPKI-RA-Application-Policies" does return something possibly useful for scenario B (I am bit hesitant as I am not familiar with templates so I am not sure if that IS representative of the same field - the naming of keys is not clear for me).   This field is not present in scenario A.

"msPKI-Asymmetric-Algorithm`PZPWSTR`ECDH_P512` ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scenario A you can read the DefaultCSPs (The list of providers that are checked). But there are some which allow more than one algorithm (like the smart card provider). Most of them have DSA, DH, RSA, etc in their names and ADCS only supports RSA, DSA and the 3 NISP P-Curves.

For scenario B you are on the right path.